# Weird output escaping in symfony 1.4

Tags: encoding, symfony1, escaping

I have the following line in my code :

```
  mb_substr(strip_tags($comm->getRawValue()->comment),0,30,'UTF-8')
```

This allows me to display only the first 30 chars of a comment.

But when the comment contains an accent at that string position, the
output is :

```
  "Ah non, on ne peut pas int&eac"
```

An html entity gets cut.

The weird behavior here is that, if I cut the string farther from the
start, it gets displayed as :

```
  "Ah non, on ne peut pas intég"
```

With no html entities, just the character 'é'.

What is going on ?

PS_ I tried adding a html_entity_decode(), but that transforms the accent in question marks.

Comment: What's in the underlying "comment" string? Is the `&eacute;` entity actually stored in `comment` as `&eacute;`?

Comment: (Incidentally, using mb_substr is just fine here, but in the future you might find Symfony's truncate_text() from the [text helper](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/helper/TextHelper.php) useful if you'd not come across it before...)

Comment: Oh. according to phpmyadmin, the entity is in the database : "Ah non, on ne peut pas int&eacute;grer". Must be TinyMCE's doing.

Comment: Is truncate_text() UTF-8 aware ?

Comment: Same behavior with : `truncate_text(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($comm->getRawValue()->comment)),36, '&hellip;')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it !
I had to add 'UTF-8' to html_entity_decode :

```
truncate_text(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($comm->getRawValue()->comment),null,'UTF-8'),40, '&hellip;');
```

Comment: Seems reasonable. Though if you can manage it, it might be best to avoid having HTML entities going into the database in the first place. It's going to get annoying at some point if you have real `é` characters and `&eacute` entities both in there.